# R using grepl across multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

I have a list of dataframes that each contain multiple of the same columns. In one of the columns, there are multiple instances where a row just contains "[]". My goal is to replace these instances with a blank.

I've attempted to do so via the map function and grepl. While it runs there is no change to the output. Am I going in the right direction here?

Please not that I differentiate between "[]" and "[value]"

I only want to replace the empty brackets with blanks.

My code below:

```
first_column <- c("1", "2", "3","4")
second_column <- c("value1", "value2","[]","[value]")
first_column_2 <- c("5", "6", "7","8")
second_column_2 <- c("value1", "[]","[]","[value2]")
first_column_3<- c("9", "10", "11","12")
second_column_3 <- c("[]", "[value2]","[]","[]")
df_1 <- data.frame(first_column,second_column)
df_2 <- data.frame(first_column_2,second_column_2)
df_3 <- data.frame(first_column_3,second_column_3)
df_list <- list(df_1,df_2,df_3)

var <- c(2)
df_list <- map(df_list, ~.x[!grepl("[[]",var),])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and `gsub` to accomplish this. `grepl` returns true or false if the pattern matches, whereas `gsub` allows you to replace matches with something else. Note that instead of specifying an empty string (`''`), you could just as easily specify `NA`, but that will depend on your definition of "blank".

Here I use base R's `lapply`, which in this case is equivalent to `purrr::map` (even the syntax is interchangeable here).

```
data <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  x %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.character), ~gsub('\\[\\]', '', .x)))
})

[[1]]
  first_column second_column
1            1        value1
2            2        value2
3            3              
4            4       [value]

[[2]]
  first_column_2 second_column_2
1              5          value1
2              6                
3              7                
4              8        [value2]

[[3]]
  first_column_3 second_column_3
1              9                
2             10        [value2]
3             11                
4             12
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few issues:

- (a) you say you want to replace `"[]"` with `""`, but your code is trying to drop them completely, not replace them. Use `sub` instead of `grepl` for replacing---or even better, since you are matching a whole string don't use regex at all
- (b) you are running `grepl` on the number 2: you have `var <- 2` and your command is `grepl("[[]",var)`, which is `grepl("[[]", 2)`, which is always `FALSE` as the string "2" doesn't contain brackets.
- (c) Your `grepl` pattern is searching for any string that contains a `[` in it. So if you correct (a) and (b), you'll still match with strings like `"[value1]"`.

As I said in (a), when you're matching a full string, you don't need regex at all. I'd do it like this:

```
df_list <- map(df_list, ~ {
  .x[[var]][.x[[var]] == "[]"] = ""
  .x
})
df_list
# [[1]]
#   first_column second_column
# 1            1        value1
# 2            2        value2
# 3            3              
# 4            4       [value]
# 
# [[2]]
#   first_column_2 second_column_2
# 1              5          value1
# 2              6                
# 3              7                
# 4              8        [value2]
# 
# [[3]]
#   first_column_3 second_column_3
# 1              9                
# 2             10        [value2]
# 3             11                
# 4             12
```